# Тогда же, как и

Tags: выбор-слов, согласование, союзы

Допустимо это как разговорный вариант или во второй части может быть только "когда"? Например:

> У него воду отключили тогда же, **как** и у тебя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наряду с формальным "тогда же, когда (и)" мне видится более естественным вариант *"тогда же, **что** и..."* - посмотрел в книгах, есть достаточно много совпадений. Вероятно, потому, что местоимение "что" более универсально (может указывать на подразумеваемый "тот же срок, что", "то же время, что"), *тогда как* (!) сочетание "**тогда** и **как**" (пусть и разделенное частицей) несет *противительную* окраску, с которой не очень хорошо  сочетается заложенная "утвердительность" ("тогда же").

Comment: Спасибо, очень интересное наблюдение!

Comment: Полагаю, что здесь нет противительной окраски.  Значение сопоставления может иметь сочетание "тогда же как" в значении "в то время как", но здесь этого нет.

Answer (score 1):

***У него** воду отключили **тогда же, как и** у тебя.*

Сравнить: ***У него, как и у тебя**, воду отключили тогда же.*

Грамматика в заданном примере верная, но стилистика не самая лучшая. Здесь плохая сочетаемость местоимений ***тогда же, как*** поэтому вариант **разговорный**.

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

Поэтому немцы поспешили оттуда эвакуироваться **заранее:** примерно **тогда же, как и** из Киркенеса. [И. М. Дьяконов. Книга воспоминаний. Часть вторая. Глава пятая (1944-1945) (1995)]

**Он** был следствием ревизии графа Головкина и вышел бы **тогда же, как и** столовые деньги мои...[И. М. Долгоруков. (1788-1822)]

**Кирилл Арсеньевич** был отмечен Петром I    и в числе других стольников **тогда же, как и** князь Дмитрий Михайлович Голицын, был отправлен за границу. [Ф. Е. Зарин-Несвицкий. Борьба у престола (1913)]

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon!